# Sending the same form with 1 different field n number of times

Tags: javascript

Right now, I have 3 part of my code working:

- I have a form that I wish to add n number of names.
- The names are put into an array.
- A loop iterates through the array with a delay

But I want to submit the form on every iteration with the new name attached.

The form is always submitted (target is an iframe) with the last name yet you can see from my debugging commented out code that an alert will pop up (with a delay) for every name in the array.

```
<script>
function getUsers() 
{
    var separateUsers = document.getElementById("Requestors").value.split("\n");
    //document.write(separateUsers[1]);
    for (var i=0;i<separateUsers.length;i++)
    {
        sleep(400);
        document.sendForm.userName.value = (separateUsers[i]);
        //alert("Loop iteration "+separateUsers[i]+ " " +i+ " out of"+ i);
        document.getElementById("sendForm").submit();
        //document.write(sendForm.userName.value);
    }
}

function sleep(ms)
{
    var dt = new Date();
    dt.setTime(dt.getTime() + ms);
    while (new Date().getTime() < dt.getTime());
}   

</script>

<form name ="sendForm" id="sendForm" action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="theTarget">
    <input type="hidden"  name="userName" id="userName" value="" />
</form>

<form name ="initialForm">
    <textarea name="Requestors" cols="10" rows="10" value= ""></textarea>
    <input type="button" onclick="getUsers()" value="Submit" />
</form>
<iframe id="theTarget" name ="theTarget" ></iframe>
```

Comment: Hint: Use `onload` attribute on the `IFRAME`. Note: `alert` will always pause the script.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too good on hints :(. Do you mean have the onload trigger as an alert to say the iframe has loaded thus not stopping the script as seen when I use the alert within the for loop? If i do this the alert box appears as you load the page (as expected) but only appears once more rgardless of how many names are added.